# how to resolve' NameError: name 'imaplib' is not defined' (python poetry)

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I spend a lot of time resolving this problem but I couldn't,
So I want someone to help me.

I'm beginner for python and use poetry.

When I import imaplib I always get an error.
**' NameError: name 'imaplib' is not defined'**

I know I don't need to install imaplib'.
what should I do then?

This below is my code.

Thank you for your reading and kindness.
I appreciate it.

---

```
import imaplib
import email

host = 'imap.gmail.com'
username = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'
password = 'xxxxxxxx'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
mail.login(username, password)
mail.select('inbox')
_, search_data = mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN')

for num in search_data[0].split():
    # print(num)
    _, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    # print(data[0])
    _, b = data[0]
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(b)
    #email_message = email.message_from_string(b)

    # print(email_message)
    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain' or part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            print(body)
        print(search_data)
```

Comment: hi, interesting, what version of python are you using? `imaplib` should be built-in...

Comment: Thank you for your confirm. Perhaps I use python2 because I don’t know how to update. I try to update python3.8 anyhow!

Comment: I updated python3.8 but I could't resolve it....so sad.

Comment: I wrote this script in another sheet then suddnly I resolved it. I don't know why. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Run: `pip install imap` and install **imap** package at your OS. (for example on Archlinux: `yay imap`)